# matlab test for normal distribution (not test for non-normal distribution)

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have a set of about 100000 numbers.   Fitting a gaussian to my data I can visually see that the points follow a gaussian almost exactly.   Using the normplot I see that my data again follow a gaussian except for a little noise on the tails.

Now, what I am looking for is a function that can give me a p-value that rejects the null hypothesis that my data aren't normal.   Lilleforfs, and Jbtest have the null hypothesis that the data are normal.   I can reject the null hopotheses if I subsample my data down to about 100 points.

What I really want is to reject the hypothesis that my data are not normally distributed, with some associated p-value.   Is this possible?

edit:   my data are integers in the range of 1 to 100.

Probably should have kept my notes from 3rd year stats.

Comment: I think the quick answer is 'no', but you might be better asking this on stats.stackexchange.com (I'm not sure how to migrate it).

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible in the way you are asking: there's a reason normality tests don't have the null hypothesis be that the data *aren't* normally distributed.

The way a traditional, frequentist hypothesis test works is by using the null hypothesis to characterize a *null distribution* of your test statistic. At that point, unusual values of your test statistic (that is, ones that are unusually high or low within your null distribution) signal that something is wrong- it is unlikely you would get a value like this if the null hypothesis were true. In a test where the null hypothesis is that the data is normal, this is easy. We know a lot about the normal distribution, so we can describe what the null distribution of the test statistic will look like.

But now consider an imaginary test where the null hypothesis is that the data is *not* normally distributed. Under this null hypothesis, what does our test statistic (whichever we choose) look like? We don't know, because *it could be almost any distribution!* It could be gamma, beta, log-normal, exponential, Cauchy, or one we've never heard of. There are literally infinite possible distributions it could follow, so saying "what would this data look like under that hypothesis" doesn't work.

ETA: If your data are integers, it is impossible that they are normally distributed, as the normal distribution is continuous. Perhaps they are [binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)?

Answer (score 1):

You can look into ktest, a one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. Basically it checks if your data set is normally distributed with some significance value.